# How to flip an image and have it display correctly in all states

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiimage

I needed to flip and image and then add it to a button. I used the following code

```
UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
playButton.frame = CGRectMake(xing, ying, dx,dy);
[playButton setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playButton addTarget:self action:function forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Begin-Set-Button.png"];
UIImage * other = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:buttonImageNormal.CGImage
                    scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
UIImage * awesome = [other stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:awesome forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It displays the image correctly, yet when I click on it, the buttons displays the unflipped image.

In my attempt to fix this I added the following line of code

```
[playButton setBackgroundImage:awesome forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Yet when I click on the button, it does not darken the color like it does for buttons that I create with the unflipped image.

How do I code it so that when I use a flipped image, it shows the flipped image darkened when it is pressed? I know how to manually darken the image, but I was wondering if there was a way to automatically do it with a simple function call?

Comment: have you tried using setImage?

Comment: @Joel just tried it. Still shows the unflipped image when selected.

Comment: Are you setting the buttons backgroundImage in IB too or just in the code that you are showing us?

Comment: @Joel The button is coded, so there is no IB. This is all the code that I put into making the button

Comment: I will take look at this tonight and get back to you. No promises, but I will look at it and let you know!

Comment: Wow... I honestly have no idea why that is. I cannot figure a nice way around it. The only thing that sort of worked (but not really) was setting the alpha to like .9 that way it highlighted a little bit. Otherwise the only thing I can think of is creating two images but that seems unbelievably redundant. Sorry.

Comment: Oh man this was really giving me a hard time thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of flipping the image. Have you tried flipping the imageView?

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"path/to-image.png"];

UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI); // flip the image view
[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This is what I did to keep the selection state highlighting and not have to deal with the image flipping.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as well and so I did a search to see this post. I suspected that perhaps the image is not "solidified" and so the mirror operation is not permanent.

Checking out the docs for "imageWithCGImage:" shows the following:

**Discussion**
*This method does not cache the image object. You can use the methods of the Core Graphics framework to create a Quartz image reference.*

And so, the mirroring of the image does not hold for events unless a new image is created in a new context. I've also been working on a method to draw an image on an arbitrary size canvas to create buttons with the same background. You can use this method to create an image that maintains CG operations, such as mirroring:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCanvasSize:(CGSize)canvasSize withImage:(UIImage *)anImage
{
    if (anImage.size.width > canvasSize.width ||
        anImage.size.height > canvasSize.height)
    {
        // scale image first
        anImage = [anImage scaleWithAspectToSize:canvasSize];
    }

    CGRect targetRect = CGRectZero;
    CGFloat xOrigin = (canvasSize.width - anImage.size.width) / 2;
    CGFloat yOrigin = (canvasSize.height - anImage.size.height) / 2;
    targetRect.origin = CGPointMake(xOrigin, yOrigin);
    targetRect.size = anImage.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, NO, anImage.scale);
    [anImage drawInRect:targetRect];

    UIImage *canvasedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return canvasedImage;    
}

- (UIImage*)scaleWithAspectToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    CGSize scaledSize = newSize;

    float scaleFactor = 1.0;

    if (self.size.width > self.size.height)
    {
        scaleFactor = self.size.width / self.size.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height / scaleFactor;
    }
    else
    {
        scaleFactor = self.size.height / self.size.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width / scaleFactor;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scaledSize, NO, 0.0);
    CGRect scaledImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height);
    [self drawInRect:scaledImageRect];

    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return scaledImage;
}
```